# Quiero conectar mi android App de React Native con el backend que tengo en heroku

Tags: javascript, react-native, heroku

Quiero realizar esta conexión para poder verificar el Login, el Sign-up, etc. Todo lo que viene a ser la base de datos. La cuestión es que no se como realizar esta conexión, y capaz alguien de la comunidad me podría ayudar.

Answer (score 0):

Para la conexión vas a precisar la ip/puerto del servidor. Si el servidor ya esta desarrollado, tendrías que consultar con el desarrollador/la doc del api/endpoint para conocer los métodos a llamar y los parámetros.
Si no esta hecho, tenes que subir tu código a Heroku y configurar tu cuenta, hay tutoriales para eso en Heroku.

Si la pregunta viene por como hacer la llamada al endpoint desde React, esto podes hacerlo como llamando a cualquier endpoint:

```
fetch('http://serverip:port/method/')
  .then(({ results }) => this.setState({ results: results }));
```